# Cassandra UnavailableException with one node up and replication factor is 1, ordered partitioned

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Hello, I got a problem when getting some data from Cassandra. 
My cluster had following attributions:
1. Ordered partitioner. The cluster had 10 nodes, and using ByteOrderedPartitioner.
2. Replication was 1. The cluster was in SimpleStrategy with replication factor is 1.

When I started up only a node, and to get some data from that node(I was sure that the desired data was stored in the only started node), UnavailableException throwed.

Anybody could give some suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you check that the data was there? What consistency level did you use?

Comment: I use nodetool to return the endpoint for a specific key, and it supposes to be the only node which I have started. The consistency level is ONE.

Comment: Any errors in system.log?